# Add a list to another list but without adding the first element?

Tags: c#, list

I have 2 lists. I want add list 2 to list 1. But the first element of list 2 are not required to be added. Any way (not using for-loop) to do it? Thanks.

```
List<int> l1 = new List<int>{1, 2, 3};
List<int> l2 = new List<int>{4, 5, 6};
```

results are `{1, 2, 3, 5, 6}`.

Comment: Does l1.addrange(l2.skip(1)) not work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use `Skip`

```
l1.AddRange(l2.Skip(1));
```

Comment: Does the skip create a new list or just a wrap?

Comment: @user1899020 `Enumerable.Skip` returns a lazy iterator, it doesn't create a new list. Once you invoke `Enumerable.ToList`, you create a new list. Since you're storing integers which are value types, a copy will be made of those integers in the fresh list.

Answer (score 2):

You can use linq:

```
l1.AddRange(l2.Skip(1));
```

**<kbd>[demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/sWt9ru)</kbd>**

Answer (score 1):

You can use Where clause:

```
l1.AddRange(l2.Where((x,i)=>i>0));
```

Where x represents element and i is an index of that element. It will collect all elements except where index is 0 and that's what you want.